# Remove Empty row in gridview which is added automatically at the bottom of gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, grid

I am using grid view to show records from database. Gridview has pagination and `pagesize` is set as `15`. And one column has link field when user click this link it proceed some functionality. Now what is my problem is

- 1) when number of records less than page size the last page is
  shrunk. it's k for me. but on clicking view link in grid view the
  empty row added automatically. how do i remove these empty row?
- 2) on clicking view link the page index changed to 1. example i am in
  3 page of grid view and clicking view link in 3rd page the page index
  number changed to 1 but the page shows 3rd row record. how do i fix
  this..?

please any can help me.. thanks in advance

grid view code:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGRNListAll" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Style="width: 100%;"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="15" OnPageIndexChanging="gvGRNListAll_PageIndexChanging"
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"
    GridLines="None">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="10%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LocationName" HeaderText="Location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierName" HeaderText="Supplier Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="GRNNo" HeaderText="GRN No" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="InvoiceNo" HeaderText="In.No">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="GRNDate" HeaderText="GRNDate" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" SortExpression="ExId" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Blue">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnStoreCode" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("StoreCode") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnGRNNo" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("GRNNo") %>' />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbView" OnClick="lbView_Click" runat="server" Text="View"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ControlStyle ForeColor="#FF3300" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridHeaderROW" Width="10%" />
            <ItemStyle CssClass="GridItemROW" Width="10%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EmptyDataRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Bottom" ForeColor="#FF3300" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No Records Found.
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

On `PageIndexChanged`

```
protected void gvGRNListAll_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvGRNListAll.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    SearchData();
    gvGRNListAll.PageIndex = 0;
}
```

Searchdata Code :

```
public void SearchData()
    {
       DataTable dtGRN = objBAL.FilterGRNScannedList("filterGRNScannedList", suppliercode, grnno, locationcode, Fromdate, Todate, "");
       gvGRNListAll.DataSource = dtGRN; 
       gvGRNListAll.DataBind();
    }
```

Onclick event Code :

```
if (sender is LinkButton)
        {
            GridViewRow gvrCurrent = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            hdnGRNNo = (HiddenField)gvrCurrent.FindControl("hdnGRNNo");
            hdnStore = (HiddenField)gvrCurrent.FindControl("hdnStoreCode");
            gvGRNListAll.Rows[gvrCurrent.RowIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Empty;
            gvGRNListAll.Rows[gvrCurrent.RowIndex].BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D8D8D8");
            if (hdnGRNNo != null && hdnStore != null)
            {
                GetGRNListForNo(hdnGRNNo.Value, Convert.ToInt32(hdnStore.Value));
            }
        }
```

Comment: i have edit my question with code sample

Comment: in code behind i just bind the data source to gridview

Comment: So what are you doing at `OnPageIndexChanging="gvGRNListAll_PageIndexChanging"`. Also show the bind code.

Comment: sorry its a spelling mistake. page size is 15

Comment: i have edited my question with code behind code.

Comment: what is `SearchData` here ? Also show the code related to this. If you are using `PageIndexChanging` you need  to set the object of the datatable. I guess you are missing something

Comment: try giving `ViewLink` button as `CausesValidation=false` and see whether still the `PageIndex` change

Comment: It's not working. still i have same problem

Comment: is still the`PageIndex` changed ??

Comment: Yes, its changed to 1

Comment: something strange, what is the code `onClick` of view button. show us

Comment: i have updated on click event code

Answer (score 0):

on `RowDataBound` do something like below

```
private void gvGRNListAll_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[6].Text == "")    // here add the cell no at which the row is coming blank.
    e.Row.Visible = false;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: you need to set the `Cells[]` properly in the gridview starting from count `0` and add the cell no, on the column which you want to remove